# Setting the language in AppControler not working

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to set the language in cakephp based on user preferences.

It works if I change Config.language directly in config.php
It works if I set it in bootstrap.php like this:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
```

But it is **not working** if I set it in AppController.php in beforefilter.:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
  Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Is your `beforeFilter()` method overridden somewhere in a child controller like say the `UsersController` ?

Comment: yes, sometimes.. but I am using always parent::beforeFilter(); and there is nothing language specific (Configure.write..) in other controllers.

Comment: How is not working, what do you see?

Comment: @toby1kenobi I see the language which is set in the config.php (Config.language). It won't change if I change it in the controller in beforeFilter using Configure::write.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - there is no 'config.php' in a standard CakePHP installation is there? Is this something you're doing yourself? Or is it core.php? If it's core.php, can you *not* set the language there, only do it in your beforeFilter?